# Pass argument to function that is stored as a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am making a virtual terminal for a basic hacking game.
Commands need to be given by user. Commands are stored as a dictionary, like the following

```
commandslist = {"systemtime": systemtime(),
            "ping": ping(),
            "pwd": pwd(),
            "ifconfig": ifconfig(),
            "help": helpmenu(),
            "shop": shop()}
```

That references the actual functions

```
def ifconfig():
    ipaddr = user["ipaddr"]
    return ipaddr
def ping(ip4="127.0.0.1"):
    if ip4 in enemyuser["ipaddr"]:
        x = "64 bytes from " + ip4 +": icmp_seq=1"
    else:
        x ="No ping response"
    return x
```

The code in main.py reads for user input and for loops to find it. I dont want a bunch of messy if statements

```
while 1:
userinput = input(bash)
if " " in userinput:
    command, options = userinput.split(" ")
else: 
    command = userinput
for i in commandslist:
    if i == command:
        print(commandslist[i])
```

Basically I need to pass the ip address of enemy computer to the ping command but I can't figure out a way if I could update the ping() call in the dictionary to include the options that would be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this isn't directly the problem you're asking about, but `{"systemtime": systemtime()}` calls the `systemtime` function when the dictionary is created, not when the `"systemtime"` key is accessed! This means all your functions will run immediately at the start, then never again. You can fix this by storing the functions, without calling them:

```
commandslist = {"systemtime": systemtime,
                "ping": ping,
                "pwd": pwd,
                "ifconfig": ifconfig,
                "help": helpmenu,
                "shop": shop}
```

I mention this because once you've made that fix, this is a lot easier to solve (and, it's far more correct).

First, I'd modify the line that cuts up the user input, since it's a little off as well for more complicated cases:

```
 command, *options = userinput.split(" ")
```

Note the `*`. This will collect every element after the first into `options`. That means if the user enters `somecommand arg1 arg2 arg3`, `options` will hold `(arg1, arg2, arg3)`.

After that runs, use `command` to do a lookup to fetch the chosen function:

```
func = commandslist[command]
```

Then apply the `options` arguments to the function:

```
func(*options)
```

`*options` expands the sequence of options they gave into the argument list of the `func` function.

Something like:

```
userinput = input(bash)
command, *options = userinput.split(" ")
func = commandlist[command]
print(func(*options))
```

---

Also, the whole

```
for i in commandslist:
    if i == command:
```

part doesn't make sense if you think about it. You're checking for `i` to be equal to `command`. But if they're equal, why not just use `command` directly like I'm showing? Yours will silently fail if they enter a bad command, when you likely want to actual show an error to them.

Also note, you'll want to do error handling, or do an `if command in commandslist` check ahead of time. If the user enters a not existent key, or the wrong number of arguments, this will crash. You'll want to catch the `KeyError`, and the `TypeError` from the wrong number of arguments.